# How to read an xml resource in a Spring MVC application?

Tags: maven, spring-mvc

I am using Spring MVC and Maven to build a web app.
I have placed an xml file under src/main/resources and I am trying to read this file from my Controller. Can someone please provide the config and code to do so?

Many thanks

Comment: Give more details.  Perhaps answer this: what is in the xml file?  Is it pingpong balls?  Maybe java properties?  How about application specific configuration that is in on way spring configuration?

Comment: It is a saml metadata file so let's consider it as a custom valid xml file which I want to read into a String from the Controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your controller, create a field (as a property, i.e. with getter/setter) of type org.springframework.core.io.Resource

In your bean config for the controller, set the value of that property to the path of the Resource, like this:

```
<bean id="myController" class="...">
  <property name="xmlFile" value="some/resource/path/myFile.xml"/>
</bean>
```

Spring will use this config to populate the property with a Resource object that provides access to the resource with the specified path. That Resource object then provides several methods to read the content of the resource, e.g. getInputStream().

See http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/resources.html for more detailed information, especially chapters 5.2 and 5.6

Comment: Hi Jan, Thanks for the advice. It seems to be working (although I had to provide the classpath: prefix for the value name). The problem I'm having now is that the String converstion seems to be encoded but I suppose it is now a problem with how I read the resource

Comment: Hi again, for some reason when I display the resource it "cuts" all the xml tags leaving me only with the values inside. Any idea why...?

Comment: You mean you display it in the browser? Then the browser is probably rendering the XML as HTML and ignores all tags are not valid HTML tags, which leaves only the text nodes of the XML. If you select "Show source" in your browser, does it display the XML tags in the HTML source view? Then set "Content-Type" header to "text/xml" in the HttpServletResponse, that should fix it for most browsers.

Answer (score 1):

2 ways you can get this done:

- If you have a session then

> request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath(...)

- if your Controller extends org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController
  then you can just call

> ```
> getServletContext().getRealPath(...)
> ```

Put something like this:

```
public String processSubmit(HttpServletRequest request,@ModelAttribute("myModel") MyModer model, BindingResult result, SessionStatus status){
request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath(...)
}
```

Comment: My Controller is annotated with @Controller doesn't extend AbstractController, I also don't have a request object in hand as I am doing this from a method that processes a form submit: public String processSubmit(@ModelAttribute("myModel") MyModer model, BindingResult result, SessionStatus status). Any ideas.....?

Comment: Put a HttpServletRequest as your parameter and use

Comment: getClass().getResourceAsStream("myFile.xml") is throwing NullPointerException. Are you sure I don't need to configure anything in the Spring xml?

Comment: please post your code... you should get it from servletcontext and not from class loader

Comment: You are right, I wasn't using it from the right context however I think I prefer the solution from Jan, just trying it now :)